# How to set up Spring Kafka test using EmbeddedKafkaRule/ EmbeddedKafka to fix TopicExistsException Intermittent Error?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have been having issues with testing my Kafka consumer and producer. The integration tests fail intermittently with `TopicExistsException`.

This is how my current test class - `UserEventListenerTest` looks like for one of the consumers:

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["application.kafka.user-event-topic=user-event-topic-UserEventListenerTest",
    "application.kafka.bootstrap=localhost:2345"])
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class UserEventListenerTest {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    @Value("\${application.kafka.user-event-topic}")
    private lateinit var userEventTopic: String

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaConfigProperties: KafkaConfigProperties

    private lateinit var embeddedKafka: EmbeddedKafkaRule
    private lateinit var sender: KafkaSender<String, UserEvent>
    private lateinit var receiver: KafkaReceiver<String, UserEvent>

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        embeddedKafka = EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, false, userEventTopic)
        embeddedKafka.kafkaPorts(kafkaConfigProperties.bootstrap.substringAfterLast(":").toInt())
        embeddedKafka.before()

        val producerProps: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to kafkaConfigProperties.bootstrap,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to "com.project.userservice.config.MockAvroSerializer"
        )
        val senderOptions = SenderOptions.create<String, UserEvent>(producerProps)
        sender = KafkaSender.create(senderOptions)

        val consumerProps: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to kafkaConfigProperties.bootstrap,
            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to kafkaConfigProperties.deserializer,
            ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to "earliest",
            "schema.registry.url" to kafkaConfigProperties.schemaRegistry,
            ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG to "test-consumer"
        )
        val receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create<String, UserEvent>(consumerProps)
            .subscription(Collections.singleton("some-topic-after-UserEvent"))
        receiver = KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
    }
}

// Some tests
// Not shown as they are irrelevant
...
...
...
```

The `UserEventListener` class consumes a message from `user-event-topic-UserEventListenerTest` and publishes a message to `some-topic-after-UserEvent`.

As you can see from the setup, I have a test producer that will publish a message to `user-event-topic-UserEventListenerTest` so that I can test whether `UserEventListener` consumes the message and a test consumer that will consume the message from the `some-topic-after-UserEvent` so that I can see if `UserEventListener` publishes a message to `some-topic-after-UserEvent` after processing the record.

The `KafkaConfigProperties` class is as follows.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.kafka")
data class KafkaConfigProperties(
    var bootstrap: String = "",
    var schemaRegistry: String = "",
    var deserializer: String = "",
    var userEventTopic: String = "",
)
```

And the `application.yml` looks like this.

```
application:
  kafka:
    user-event-topic: "platform.user-events.v1"
    bootstrap: "localhost:9092"
    schema-registry: "http://localhost:8081"
    deserializer: com.project.userservice.config.MockAvroDeserializer
```

## Error logs

```
com.project.userservice.user.UserEventListenerTest > initializationError FAILED
    kafka.common.KafkaException:
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.createTopics(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:354)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.lambda$createKafkaTopics$4(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:341)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.doWithAdmin(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:368)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.createKafkaTopics(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:340)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:284)
        at org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.EmbeddedKafkaRule.before(EmbeddedKafkaRule.java:114)
        at com.project.userservice.user.UserEventListenerTest.setup(UserEventListenerTest.kt:62)

        Caused by:
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'user-event-topic-UserEventListenerTest' already exists.
            at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:104)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:272)
            at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.createTopics(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:351)
            ... 6 more

            Caused by:
            org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'user-event-topic-UserEventListenerTest' already exists.
```

## What I have tried:

- Use different bootstrap server address in each test by specifying the bootstrap configuration, e.g. `@SpringBootTest(properties = ["application.kafka.bootstrap=localhost:2345"])`
- Use different topic names in each test by overwriting the topic configuration via `@SpringBootTest` just like the bootstrap server overwrite in the previous bullet point
- Add `@DirtiesContext` to each test class

## Package versions

- Kotlin 1.3.61
- Spring Boot - 2.2.3.RELEASE
- io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka:1.2.2.RELEASE
- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:2.3.4.RELEASE (test implementation only)

## Problem

I have multiple test classes that use `EmbeddedKafkaRule` and are set up more or less the same away. For each of them, I specify different kafka bootstrap server address and topic names, but I still see the TopicAlreadyExists exceptions intermittently.

What can I do to make my test classes consistent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I specify different kafka bootstrap server address and topic names, but I still see the TopicAlreadyExists exceptions intermittently

That makes no sense; if they have a new port each time, and especially new topic names, it's impossible for the topic(s) to already exist.

Some suggestions:

1. Since you are using JUnit5, don't use the JUnit4 `EmbeddedKafkaRule`, use `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` instead; or simply add `@EmbeddedKafka` and the broker will be added as a bean to the Spring application context and its life cycle managed by Spring (use `@DirtiesContext` to destroy); for non-Spring tests, the broker will be created (and destroyed) by the JUnit5 `EmbeddedKafkaCondition` and is available via `EmbeddedKafkaCondition.getBroker()`.
2. Don't use explicit ports; let the broker use its default random port and use `embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString()` for the bootstrap servers property.
3. If you must manage the brokers yourself (in `@BeforeAll`), `destroy()` them in `@AfterAll`.

Comment: I didn't `EmbeddedKafkaRule` was for JUnit4, I'll try update my test class as per your suggestion. Re: explicit ports, I currently get the broker address by injecting to my kafka listener classes, i.e. via `KafkaConfigProperties` which is a `ConfigurationProperties` and it gets its value from `application.yml`. I tried to update the value to `${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}` but hasn't been successful. I think the reason might be that `KafkaConfigProperties` is initialised before `EmbeddedKafka` has set that value. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Actually, after I changed it to use `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation, the test works consistently. One question though, I do not specify the topic, but the topic got created correctly. Is it because of the kafka listener class - `UserEventListener`? i.e. does the consumer auto create the topic if it doesn't exist? `allow.auto.create.topics` defaults to `true`?

Comment: For the first comment, set the `bootstrapServersProperty` [on the annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#kafka-testing-embeddedkafka-annotation) to override the value in the yaml. Yes, the broker will [auto-create topics, the property is true by default](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs).